# Why are some variables or lists preserved when exiting recursive calls and others not?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to understand what happens to your variables in Python when you exit a list. I *thought* all variables that are passed to a recursive function are pushed onto a stack.  And when you exit a stack, those variables are popped off.  However, I'm seeing this is not the case.

I created a simple recursive string function to test this. When I run this code:

```
def recursiveArr(n, listB):

    if(n==0):
        return True;
    else:
        listB.append(n);
        listC = listB;
        recursiveArr(n-1, listB[:]);
        print(n)
        print(listB)
```

I get the following output:

```
1
[4, 3, 2, 1]
2
[4, 3, 2]
3
[4, 3]
4
[4]
[4]
```

This suggests that both the list and the variable `n` were preserved on the stack. Then, I modified the call to `recursiveArr(n-1, listB)`

I got the following output:

```
1
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
2
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
4
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

From these two runs, I came to the conclusion that simple integer variables are always preserved and lists are only preserved if you pass in a copy of the list and all of its values. Here's where the tricky bit is.

I wrote some code to print the permutations of a string.  It works, but I have to decrement `level`, pop off the last instance of the result array, and decrement the respective count value in order to get my variables where they should be post-recursive call, even when I pass in just the values of result or count array.

Here's the code:

```
def stringify(theList):
    theString = ''

    return theString.join(theList)
def getPerm(charArray, countArray, result, level, lenOrigString): 
    if(level == lenOrigString):
        print(stringify(result))
        return
    for i in range(len(charArray)):
        if (countArray[i]!=0):
            result.append(charArray[i])
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1;
            level = level + 1;
            getPerm(charArray, countArray, result, level, lenOrigString)
            result.pop(len(result)-1)
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]+1
            level = level - 1;



    #print("Congratulations! You made it to the second layer!")
def printPermutations(toPerm):
    toPerm = toPerm.lower()
    lenOrigString = len(toPerm)
    charArray = [ord(iChar)-97 for iChar in toPerm]
    countArray = [];
    for iChar in range(26):
        countArray.append(0)
    for i in range(len(charArray)):
        countArray[charArray[i]] = countArray[charArray[i]] + 1
    uniqueChar = [];
    for iChar in charArray:
        if iChar not in uniqueChar:
            uniqueChar.append(iChar)
    uniqueChar = [chr(iChar+97) for iChar in uniqueChar] #keeps track of the possible characters to use
    countArray = list(filter(lambda x: x>0, countArray))#keep track of how many of each character has not been used
    uniqueChar.sort()
    result = [];
    level = 0;
    for i in range(len(uniqueChar)):
        if (countArray[i]!=0):
            result.append(uniqueChar[i])
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1;
            level = level + 1;
            getPerm(uniqueChar, countArray, result, level, lenOrigString)#call next level
            result.pop(len(result)-1)
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]+1
            level = level - 1;


printPermutations("ApPLe")
```

The code posted above works well. However, when I remove the post-call array modifications and try to get the same effect using slicing, I get results that are longer than the original string, making them not permutations.

Here's what that modified code looks like:

```
    for i in range(len(uniqueChar)):
        if (countArray[i]!=0):
            result.append(uniqueChar[i])
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1;
            level = level + 1;
            getPerm(uniqueChar, countArray[:], result[:], level, lenOrigString)#call next level
            level = level -1;
```

My question is: **why is the pattern I found in my basic string function not holding true in my string permutations function?**

I have interviews coming up and I don't want to embarrass myself by being confused about recursive exit calls.

P.S. [This is the algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYFd7VHKyWQ) I used to inspire the string permutation code.

Comment: @ggorlen: Semicolons are unusual but allowed in Python.

Comment: @colleen: It would likely help to read about the relationship between objects and variables in Python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @user2357112 I didn't know that! I guess that makes sense for separating statements on the same line. Thanks for clarifying. For the OP, I don't understand exactly the question. The code is still pretty hard to follow. `result.pop(len(result)-1)` is the same as `result.pop()` and why wouldn't you need to undo these modifications (if this is the code you're referring to)? Also, for reference, there's `print(list(itertools.permutations(some_string)))`.

Comment: The extra `[:]` slices in the recursive calls are unnecessary.

Comment: @ggorlen I didn't realize the pop thing.  I'm still somewhat new to Python.  And yes, the code I'm implementing is featured in the link at the bottom (tho the creator used Java).  I'm trying to understand why the lists don't automatically revert to what they were before making the recursive call once control returns back to that level of recursion.  Why do I have to manually pop off the last element in result?  Why doesn't the list return to the version it was prior to making the call, like it did in the basic recursive list function I mentioned first?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm doing it manually for the purpose of learning, despite there being a built-in.  And you say the [:] are redundant, but why did it make a difference in the recursiveArr function (the first code snippit posted), and preserved the list value post-exit, but they don't do the same thing in the permutations function?

Comment: You have two choices, generally speaking: you can pass a copy of the list in, using slices. In this case, there's no need to restore state after the call (although you have extra integer variables that are modified and need to be restored--sort of beside the point). The other option is to not slice the lists and push/pop on a single list the entire time. The second version is more efficient. Your code basically does both, which is basically overkill. That's why I said above you can just omit the slices. Does this make sense? The top code uses the slice approach, but it could use `pop`.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the feedback. I edited the code above so it doesn't use both at once.  My code works fine when I use pop.  However, when I use the slicing method instead of the popping method, I don't get the same effect as when I use pop.  Do you know why that is?  I'm especially confused because I got the desired behavior using slicing in the simple recursiveArr function, however, the slices are having no effect in my string permutation function.  They're behaving just like if they weren't here, which is why if I remove the pops, I get an incorrect answer, even when I use slices.

Comment: @user2357112 That was definitely useful, thanks!  I'm still a bit confused though about why slicing in the simple recursiveArr function worked to pass in only values, but it's not working in the string Permutation code, where I have to pop things at the end, even when I slice.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Let me know if there is any lingering confusion. The TL;DR is that your slicing doesn't work because the state that needs copying should be done on the copy structure, not the parent version, so it's not quite as simple as just slapping `[:]` on everything and removing the state restoration code as it is in your example version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples presented here make it somewhat difficult to follow the recursive patterns you're discussing, but your intution about references is basically correct.

In general, when traversing a call tree such as this using a list as a parameter to the recursive function, there are two approaches. The first is to pass in a copy of the list, which your first example illustrates (using the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) syntax `[:]`, which makes a copy of the entire list).

The second approach is to never copy the list and allow functions in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to refer to the same list during the entire traversal. This approach requires restoration of list state after each call resolves. We have to do this in order to preserve the logic of a copy by preventing child nodes' mutations from modifying parent state.

Here's a quick rewrite of the example function you provided to adhere to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and removes a useless line (`listC = listB;`):

```
def foo(n, lst):
    if n:
        lst.append(n)
        foo(n - 1, lst[:])
        print(f"n: {n}, lst: {lst}, id: {id(lst)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(4, [])
```

Output:

```
n: 1, lst: [4, 3, 2, 1], id: 140439070012752
n: 2, lst: [4, 3, 2], id: 140439070012832
n: 3, lst: [4, 3], id: 140439139990576
n: 4, lst: [4], id: 140439072829760
```

Note that the prints occur after the recursive calls begin resolving, so we see a fully populated list in the final call printing first. Rearrange the function to print first if this is confusing--location is irrelevant. The important part is that there is a totally distinct id per list, so we've created 4 lists in total.

Now, here's an equivalent version (in terms of output) that uses only one list the entire time and uses the "state restoration" technique described above:

```
def bar(n, lst):
    if n:
        lst.append(n)
        bar(n - 1, lst)
        print(f"n: {n}, lst: {lst}, id: {id(lst)}")
        lst.pop() # undo the append to restore state in this frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar(4, [])
```

Output:

```
n: 1, lst: [4, 3, 2, 1], id: 139793013186800
n: 2, lst: [4, 3, 2], id: 139793013186800
n: 3, lst: [4, 3], id: 139793013186800
n: 4, lst: [4], id: 139793013186800
```

Notice a few things. Firstly, logical output is the same. Convince yourself that every `append` is accompanied by a `pop` that restores state in full for the parent call, undoing all mutations performed in the current stack frame. Secondly, note that we have one list the entire time, with id 139793013186800.

Keep in mind that in a recursive call stack, parent calls are put on hold *until all children resolve completely*, so we only ever need to worry about the state of the current frame.

---

Now that we've seen the theory, let's look at two versions of the permutation method:

```
def print_permute_copy(lst, i=0):
    if i == len(lst):
        print("".join(lst))
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(lst)):            
            cpy = lst[:]
            cpy[i], cpy[j] = cpy[j], cpy[i]
            print_permute_copy(cpy, i + 1)

def print_permute_restore(lst, i=0):
    if i == len(lst):
        print("".join(lst))
    else:
        for j in range(i, len(lst)):            
            lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
            print_permute_restore(lst, i + 1)
            lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_permute_copy(list("abc"))
    print()
    print_permute_restore(list("abc"))
```

Output:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cba
cab

abc
acb
bac
bca
cba
cab
```

We can see both are correct and produce equivalent output. The top function creates new copies of the list to hand off to children. By doing so, it doesn't have to worry about restoring its state once the list is returned from the children. The downside of this approach is that a new list needs to be created for every call, which is inefficient.

On the other hand, the restoration version simply passes one list around and performs all swaps on it. After performing a swap, it passes the mutated list to its children who also perform swaps on it, but each one reverses any swaps that it performs once its children operate on the list (and eventually undo their swaps).

The code you've shown has much more complicated state, but let's examine this snippet:

```
for i in range(len(uniqueChar)):
    if (countArray[i]!=0):
        result.append(uniqueChar[i])
        countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1;
        level = level + 1;
        getPerm(uniqueChar, countArray[:], result[:], level, lenOrigString)
        level = level -1;
```

The attempt at using slicing fails because `countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1` (clearer as `countArray[i] -= 1`) is not performed on the copy, but on the parent list. Same for `result.append(uniqueChar[i])`--this should be performed on the copy we're preparing to hand to the child, not the parent list.

This works:

```
for i in range(len(uniqueChar)):
    if countArray[i] != 0:
        cpy = countArray[:]
        cpy[i] = cpy[i] - 1;
        level = level + 1;
        getPerm(uniqueChar, cpy, result + [uniqueChar[i]], level, lenOrigString)
        level = level -1;
```

Note that this is less efficient than the "state restoration" approach in the original, so I'm showing it purely for demonstration purposes. Also note that `result + [uniqueChar[i]]` uses list concatenation and creates a new list with the new item appended. The number of copies of all these lists explodes as the string length increases (the time complexity is O(N!) to begin with).

---

For sake of completeness, note that this function can be written simply as [`list(itertools.permutations(iterable))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Even if you choose to hand-write it for educational purposes such as this, there are much simpler algorithms than the one provided, which uses a lot of extra state and is difficult to reason about due to repeated code `getPerm` is [virtually repeated verbatim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) inside of `printPermutations`. Part of the problem is that Java is a much more verbose language than Python with very different operations and structures, so a literal translation of Java code is almost guaranteed to be non-Pythonic.

Some suggestions for adhering to Python style more closely:

- `snake_case` for variables and functions.
- `if(foo==bar):` should be written as `if foo == bar:` (uses whitespace around operators, omits unnecessary parenthesis).
- `foo=foo+1` is clearer as `foo += 1` (increment operator, whitespace around operators).
- `result.pop(len(result)-1)` is clearer as `result.pop()`.
- There's no need to use the type in variable names. Python doesn't have arrays, so `countArray` can be `counts`, `charArray` can be `characters`, etc (pluralization is a good way to denote lists).
- Semicolons are unnecessary.
- Use vertical whitespace around block statements:

  ```
  countArray = [];
  for iChar in range(26):
  ```

  should be

  ```
  counts = []

  for i in range(26):
  ```
- Avoid functions which produce [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) and prefer returning [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), following itertools:

  ```
  def permute(lst, i=0):
      if i == len(lst):
          yield lst[:]
      else:
          for j in range(i, len(lst)):            
              lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
              yield from permute(lst, i + 1)
              lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(list(permute(list("abc"))))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `listB[:]` it will create a copy of that list. Hence in your function it won't modify the original `listB` from one stack above. When you pass just `listB` as an argument then you pass the reference to the original list and hence it is the same list in every stack that is modified.

For `listB[:]` your recursive function goes like this:

```
recursiveArr(4, [])
|
| listB.append(4) --> listB is now [4]
|
+---> recursiveArr(3, [4])  <-- this list is a copy of original listB, let's denote it listB_2
      |
      | listB_2.append(3)  --> listB_2 is now [4, 3], listB is still [4]
      |
      +---> recursiveArr(2, [4, 3])  <-- this is a copy of listB_2, say listB_3
            |
            | listB_3.append(2)  --> list_3 is now [4, 3, 2], listB_2 is [4, 3] and listB is [4]
            |
            +---> and so on
```

If you pass `listB` as an argument on the other hand each call to `recursiveArr` will receive the reference to the same list object and thus append to the same list. Thus at each stack level you're looking at the same list with the same values.

Also note that whenever you have recursive functions where you carry a result list along each of the calls it's usually easier to use a generator with `yield` and `yield from` instead. For your example this could be done as follows:

```
def getPerm(charArray, countArray, level, lenOrigString): 
    if(level == lenOrigString):
        yield ''
    for i in range(len(charArray)):
        if countArray[i] != 0:
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]-1;
            yield from (charArray[i] + x for x in getPerm(charArray, countArray, level + 1, lenOrigString))
            countArray[i] = countArray[i]+1
```

Comment: Hi @a_guest.  Thanks for your reply.  Your explanation of recursiveArr makes sense.  However, this doesn't hold true in getPerm, which is why I'm confused.  Maybe you tried answering it with the yield explanation, but could you speak more?

Comment: When I pass in result[:] to getPerm, it's not creating copies of result.  It's appending to the original.

Comment: getPerm(["a","p","l","e"],  [1,2,1,1], [], 0,4)
|
| result.append("a") --> result is now ["a"]
|
+---> getPerm(["a","p","l","e"],  [1,2,1,1], ["a"], 1,4)
      |
      | result_2.append(3)  --> result_2 is now ["a","p"], result SHOULD still be ["a"], however, when the function returns, result will be ["a","p"] (or whatever it was at the deepest level.  That's why I have to include the pops)

Comment: @colleen Looking at the example code you posted, in every place you pass `result` as an argument, not `result[:]`. Hence the original list will be modified and you need to `pop` the items. If you passed `result[:]` the original list would remain unchanged. The point is that you `append` to the list *within the same recursion level* in a `for` loop. For that reason you need the `pop` in order to get a fresh list for the next iteration of the loop. This has nothing to do with the recursion. Instead you could also use `result + [charArray[i]]`; this avoids appending and popping.

Comment: the last code snippet shows how I use result[:].  The list does not remain unchanged.  Once the control comes back to that same recursive level, result is not the same, the end needs to be popped, despite using the slicing.

Comment: @colleen The problem does not lie with recursion. 3 lines above the one you quote, you do `result.append(uniqueChar[i])` and this happens within a `for` loop. So with every iteration you keep appending to the list `result`. However the sole purpose of `result` is to indicate the status of the partial string for the *next* level of recursion, so instead of doing `result.append(uniqueChar[i])` and `results[:]` you can do `results + [uniqueChar[i]]` directly and then you won't have to `pop` afterwards. If you append, you'll need to pop, independent of recursion.